# Add a Profile Exception to Validation Rule

Tags: validation, validation-rule

I have written a Validation Rule that I need to include a profile exception in. My rule is below and I can't figure out how to add an exception so that System Administrators can bypass this rule. Can someone please help me add in the Sytem Administrator exception. Thanks!

My rule is: If a field equals a certain value, another field (multi select picklist) cannot have a certain value removed from it unless you are a system admin.

Please see Rule below:

```
if( Field__c == 'Value', 
  if( 
    OR( 
      INCLUDES(Custom_Field__c,'Value') 
    ), 
    True, 
    False 
  ), 
False 
)
```

Comment: You have some redundant logic here. Can you describe in words what the validation rule is supposed to do?

Comment: Salesforce Help has [good examples of validation rules](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.usefulValidationRules.meta/usefulValidationRules/fields_useful_field_validation_formulas.htm) including how to set profile exceptions.

Comment: My rule is: If a field equals a certain value, another field  (multi select picklist) cannot have a certain value removed from it unless you are a system admin.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Checking by profile *should not be done* these days. It's inflexible, and doesn't allow you to respond quickly to changes. Instead, use a [custom permission](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custom_perms_overview.htm&type=5). First, create a new custom permission. Second, assign it to the profile(s) you want to exempt from your validation rule. Third, create your validation rule, which might look like this:

```
AND(NOT($Permission.Allowed_To_Do_Something),
    Field__c == 'value', 
    INCLUDES(PRIORVALUE(Other_Field__c),'value'),
    NOT(INCLUDES(Other_Field__c, 'value')))
```

This says: "If the user does not have permission to bypass this rule, and the first field is a specific value, and the multi-select picklist value previously contained a value, and the multi-select list no longer contains this value, trigger this validation rule."

Edit: edited based on rule description. Please feel free to adjust.

Comment: in addition to what explained above, spend 10 mins to see this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fHXkyj5TVP8

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure I'd recommend hardcoding a profile name, but if you absolutely have to do it, you do it this way:

`$Profile.Name = "System Administrator"`

The above line will compare the user's profile to the exact name, so make sure you have no typos.

Comment: Could always put the profile name in a custom setting e.g. `$Setup.Test_Custom_Setting__c.Profile_Name__c`. Can't do this with list settings though.

Comment: That's definitely up to the OP's discretion, but it's a great point. Alas, it is only good for one profile.... or many fields. :) Thanks @AntonioManente!

Answer (score 0):

You can slim this down quite a bit by cutting the redundant logic and inserting the System Administrator check.

```
AND(Field__c == 'Value', 
    !INCLUDES(Custom_Field__c, 'Value'),
    $Profile.Name != "System Administrator"
   )
```

Note that this isn't *exactly* what you described; it doesn't check for a value to be removed, but checks whether it is present at all in your multi-select picklist. However, that's probably a fair solution for what you're aiming at.