# What are the ways by which we can bypass validation rule?

Tags: validation-rule

I wanted to know What are the ways by which we can bypass validation rule?

Comment: You can't "bypass" validation rules. They're validation rules. You can, however, design rules that can't be broken in the UI but can in code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a Profile Exception to Validation Rule](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/209988/add-a-profile-exception-to-validation-rule)

Comment: by entering a value that passes the validation?

Comment: I find it easy to get them to pass validation for special cases.. like for example they want to validate for all users but a "Super user" by giving a custom permission assigned to a permission set and give it to a user.. Access it in validation rule using $Permission.permissionNameHere to determine if i need to process it. however - validation rules by design are meant to run always

Comment: I know they are validation rules, we cant bypass them but I came to know through code we can. I wanted to how through code we can bypass. Kindly help

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for something like [Formula Specific to Running User?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/113707/2995)

Comment: @Prapti - You cannot bypass them via code alone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose first question here you needs to clarify is what do you mean by bypassing the validation rules?

If you mean to write validation rule in such a way that for some users or some profiles it just don't apply then there are some links already shared in the comments,

If you are looking for a way so that you can insert, update records even if any record fail due to validation rule then you can use following methods of Database class.

`Datebase.insert(recordToInsert, allOrNone)`

> The optional allOrNone parameter specifies whether the operation
>   allows partial success. If you specify false for this parameter and a
>   record fails, the remainder of the DML operation can still succeed.
>   This method returns a result object that can be used to verify which
>   records succeeded, which failed, and why.

[Database class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm)

Remember here you are not bypassing the validation rules, with help of these methods you are only making sure that other records get saved in database.

Comment: This is a good answer, just not to the question posed by the OP

Comment: @Eric My thought is OP failed to frame their question properly, So i guessed this information could help OP in some manner. Other wise this question is already flagged to close.

Comment: @Eric I think now this answer looks more relevant.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of possible solutions to this but the simplest one is to add a field "bypass validation rules" on the user object.

Then, for all applicable rules you can add this in front:

```
(! $User.bypass_validation_rules__c ) && ...
```

So, if you want to bypass the rules (for example to ease a big data load), you just need to flip this switch on the user.