# How to prevent a field from updating with a Valadation rule

Tags: validation-rule

I am trying to prevent a field on the Account object `Servicing_Platform__c` from being changed.  Only profiles who can change it are Salesforce Administrator and System Administrator.  This field is picklist with values of Credit Processing and Core Card.  I have this at the bottom so far.

```
AND( 
$Profile.Name <> 'System Administrator', 'Salesforce Administrator' 
OR( 
ISPICKVAL(Servicing_Platform__c), "Credit Processing"), 
ISPICKVAL(Servicing_Platform__c), "Core Card")
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to prevent all other profiles to edit that field and only allow selective profiles, then you can just have it this way:

```
AND( 
    AND($Profile.Name <> 'System Administrator', $Profile.Name <> 'Sales Administrator'), 
    ISCHANGED(Servicing_Platform__c)
)
```

---

While this resolves the situation you are in, but for a better approach to use profile names in validation rules, take a look at [this approach](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/209988/add-a-profile-exception-to-validation-rule/209995#209995) too.

Comment: While this is the most literal interpretation, I would have recommended the use of custom permissions, as in [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/209995).

Comment: @sfdcfox True, this is more kind of a direct answer. If you ask my preference, its more code instead of config for validations just to keep everything at one place.

Comment: Using custom permissions allows you to respond to one-off events easier, though, without having to edit the rule (and again even the event is over) or giving users access to more power than they need (e.g. making them administrators just to edit a field). We had a lot of profile-based rules, and found out we had so many exceptions after a while it was far easier to just use custom permissions.

Comment: Agreed. I actually had a very similar implementation as you mentioned using custom permissions which proved to be very versatile and scalable.